# fetch : o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource : react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, cors

I have this error I don't know why in my back end node js I'm using cors

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 8080;
const  cors = require('cors');

require('./database/index')

const usersRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

usersRouter.configuration(router);
postRouter.configuration(router);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('port',port);
app.use('/', router);
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

my method front - end:

```
signIn = () => {
    const data = {login:this.login,password:this.password};
    const requestInfo = {
        method:'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({data}),
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', requestInfo)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error("Login Invalido..")
    })
    .then(token => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.token));
        this.props.history.push("/users");
        return;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.setState({message: e.message})
    });
}
```

error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Try running server with 127.0.0.1:8080 ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put CORS before router configuration.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 8080;
const  cors = require('cors');

require('./database/index')

const usersRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('port',port);

usersRouter.configuration(router);
postRouter.configuration(router);

app.use('/', router);
```